# How to vertically center text when using the :before modifier in CSS?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, vertical-text

This is another "how do I vertically center" question in HTML.  This one is when using the `:before` modifier.

HTML

```
<div style="border: 1px solid blue">
  <div class="status-yellow">vertically center me</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.status-yellow {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .35em .65em;
    font-size: .75em;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.status-yellow:before {
    display: inline-block;
    content:"\2022";
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
    color: yellow;
    font-size: 48px;
}
```

[Here's a CodePen showing the issue](https://codepen.io/dagostinelli/pen/vYepepW)

I have a `div` tag and I'm using the `:before` modifier to inject a bullet before the text.  When the bullet increases in size, the vertical centering doesn't work.  When the bullet is tiny (too tiny) it's all centered.  I'm missing something.  What am I missing?

Comment: Boy, wouldn't it be nice if the CSS/HTML standards would only just....

Comment: You should use flex. There was always a problem with vertical centering till flex was introduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox.

```
.status-yellow {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .35em .65em;
    font-size: .75em;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #fff;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;/*for vertical align*/
    justify-content:center;/*for horizontal align*/
}

.status-yellow:before {
        display: inline-block;
        content:"\2022";
        margin-right: 0.5rem;
        color: yellow;
        font-size: 48px;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you.  After playing, `inline-flex` works a little more closely.  Thanks for the idea!